# IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.api

Tags: java, android

I've got an error from Crashlytics

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$a@425d95c8
   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:654)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1157)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:378)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gM()
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gJ()
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.d()
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$2.onConnected()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.dU()
```

and the listed lines do not point on code lines in my app, so that is difficult to understand what is the reason of issue.

What can be the reason ?

EDITED :

I'm not using BroadcastReceiver in the app and probably the crash is connected with Google Play services, but as I guess, I don't need to register them in the AndroidManifest. I just using

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="...">

    </meta-data>

<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
    </meta-data>
```

Comment: If you are using broadcast receiver in your app, you have to register it  in manifest or you have to do it programmatically.

Comment: I do not using the BroadcastReceiver. I guess, reason is in Google Play services using

Comment: Make sure that those two meta tags inside <Application> tag.

Comment: I'm seeing it in Google Play Service 6.5. Did anyone tried to check if Google Play Services 7.0 fixes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a recent issue of Google Play Services library, [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=101198) you can see the topic about it.

Issue details :

> Reported by eygra...@gmail.com, Jan 19, 2015
>   Ever since updating to the latest Google Play Services, I've been getting a few of these crash reports. The only class I use from Google
>   Play Services is WearableListenerService, and an API client to check
>   if there is a Wear device attached. The report is slightly different
>   for each manufacturer. Here is one from Sony:

Exception trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$a@4247bdd0
       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:680)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1481)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:489)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gM()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gJ()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$4.onConnectionFailed()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.b()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage()
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: I have (I think) the same bug, but I don't understand how to fix it from this "answer". I use Google GMS and it works for almost everyone, but from one phone (a Samsung S3) I get this crash in Crashlytics, even though lots of other similar phones (Samsung S3) work fine....